# Use the element that calling eventlister inside function

Tags: javascript

How use the element that calling eventlister in a function, to append new element.

Example:

```
window.onload = function()
{   
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('image_add_product')).forEach(function(element,index)
    {
        element.addEventListener("change", input_change, false);
    });
};
```

Now i need to use that `element` inside `input_change` function, to append a new element span. Using `element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, this.nextSibling)`, get error `element is not defined`, using `this.parentNode.insertBefore(span, this.nextSibling)`, get error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertBefore')`.

What is the correct way to do that? Pls, see the comments on code.

```
function input_change(evt)
{   
    //with this operator i can access the properties of element, but...       
    var file = this.files[0];
    
    if(file.size > 1572864)
    {
        console.log("Imagem exede o tamanho máximo permitido de 1,5 MB");
        this.value = "";
        return false;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(theFile)
    {   
        return function(e)
        {   
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML ="<img src='...'/>";

            /*here is the problem
            how append span using element as reference*/

            this.parentNode.insertBefore(span, this.nextSibling);
        };
    })(file);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `evt.currentTarget` is the element that the listener was added to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `this` inside the onload of the file is the file, it is NOT the `this` outside of it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.image_add_product').forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("change", input_change, false);
});

function input_change(evt) {
  var elem = this;
  var file = elem.files[0];

  if (file.size > 1572864) {
    console.log("Imagem exede o tamanho máximo permitido de 1,5 MB");
    this.value = "";
    return false;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = "HELLO<img src='...'/>";
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(span, elem.nextSibling);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  return true;
}
```

```html
<label for="img1">
  <input type="file" id="img1" class="image_add_product" >
</label>

<label for="img2">
  <input type="file" id="img2" class="image_add_product" >
</label>
```

Comment: tks for atention man, perfect and clear explanation